# QuickReport throws "There Is No Default Printer Currently Selected" Exception

Tags: delphi, windows-services, printing

I have created a Delphi Service which prints TQuickReports.  Everything works fine if compiled and run as a Windows Application.  But when converted to operate as a service trying to create a form containing a TQuickRep component throws the exception.

This service runs fine on many other boxes but not this one in particular.  Here are some details:

- Using QuickReport version 4.07
- Box is a Windows Server 2008 operating system.
- Using Delphi 2007
- **Printer.Printers.Count** is returning a positive value.  In fact I can list out all of the printers.
- I have tried running the service both using Local System Account and Logged on as an Admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a new dword **UserSelectedDefault** with the value: 1 in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\SessionDefaultDevices\Session_ID

Make sure you have a local printer selected.

Comment: I think the other answer solved the problem.  But will keep this in mind.

Comment: Having a local printer (even though there was not physically one attached) resolved issue.

Answer (score 6):

**Is** there a default printer set up in session 0? Remember that under Vista / Server 2008 / Windows 7, services run in a separate session. Whether or not the logged-in user has a default printer set is not relevant - it's a per-session setting and doesn't affect session 0.

Can you rewrite the code to gracefully handle that exception and pick a printer to use?

Comment: This is new to me.  No, I was not aware there were "sessions".  How do I get a handle to a specific "Session"?

Answer (score 2):

You might give the user a way to select the printer for the service. The Windows service probably does not have a default printer set.

Set `TQuickRep.PrinterSettings.PrinterIndex` to set the printer number. Then, `TQuickRep.Print` to print the report.

Comment: In fact this is EXACTLY what we do.  Essentially the printer is specified by name and then we have a routine which will scan the Printer.Printers array and return the integer.  Problem is I can't even get to this point; I can't even create a TQuickRep instance.

Comment: @M Schenkel, seems like a bug, but the work around is probably to set the default printer prior to creating your TQuickRep object.

Comment: Can you post the code around where the error happens?  We have implemented a variation on the solution suggested by Marcus Adams for printing Quick Report reports via a Windows Service and do not see the error that you do on Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague ended up finding the solution.  I should have added these are "network" printers and not Local printers (at the time I didn't think this was related to the problem).  So the service needed to be installed with "NetworkService" as the user account under the logon tab.  From the Windows Help:

> To specify that the service uses the Network Service account, click This account, and
>   then type NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Answer (score 2):

We had a simular problem here. Using TS servers, Citrix and Powerfuse 9.
Powerfuse had all printers capitalized, however they were shared in a mixed case.
This combination caused Delphi/QReport to crash

When all printers are from printserver to powerfuse in the same case (not important upper or lower or even mixed), the problem was gone

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a Delphi(5) problem. The comparison of the available printers and the default printer is case sensitive (Printers.pas):

```
if TPrinterDevice(Objects[I]).Device = Device then
begin
   with TPrinterDevice(Objects[I]) do
      SetPrinter(PChar(Device), PChar(Driver), PChar(Port), 0);
   Exit;
end;
```

Changing the comparison to:
if `lowercase(TPrinterDevice(Objects[I]).Device) = lowercase(Device)`
solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If using terminal services 2008, same user for multiple sessions, you should look into the:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\SessionDefaultDevices\Session_ID
```

instead of

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved  a similar problem: If a Delphi application (or service) uses QuickReport, it runs before the system loads the default printer (or printers).

- When QuickReport executes `TQRPrinter.Init`, the  `printer.printers.count` is zero,
- shortly after the system loads, the `printer.printers.count` is the number of printers,
- but `tqrprinter.int` has already executed, so `TQRPrinter.FPrinterOK` is false,
- you then see this error when you try open a QuickReport.

The solution for me was wait until the printers were loaded before launching the application (in citrix and terminal server). I solved this in two ways, either by overwriting `tqrprinter` or delay the `dpr`.